# Add the values of duplicate record in SQL and display it in a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am using Microsoft Report Builder to build my reports.  I also have a SQL Server database.

I have the following table.  Please run the snippet to get a visual representation of my SQL table.

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Timesheet
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      Jacob
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      Jacob
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      John
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to add all the values of the duplicate records in the timesheets column and display the result in the timesheet column with the name in the name column.  No duplicate record should be shown.

Please run the following code snippet to get a visual representation of what I want the table to look like based on the previous table

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Timesheet
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      Jacob
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      5
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      John
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I basically want the duplicate records' timesheets column to be added together.
Is there maybe someway I could do this in report builder which will be easier then SQL Server?

Comment: You would need to use grouping on Name in your reports and the SUM all the values in Timesheet. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/grouping-pane-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above issues maybe you want like this please check this example.

> SQL Query

```
DECLARE @EMP TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Timesheet INT
);
INSERT INTO @EMP VALUES('Jacob',2),('Jacob',3),('John',1)

SELECT * FROM @EMP

SELECT Name,SUM(Timesheet) AS Timesheet
FROM @EMP
GROUP BY Name
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, much simpler then i initially thought

Comment: Welcome, brother :)

Comment: How would i do the same thing but i have a users table and a timesheets table and a overtime table.  I want to display the names from users table, timesheets from timesheets table and overtime from overtime table as one table ex Name, Timesheets, Overtime.  They should also get grouped by the name but i tried to full outer join the users table with timesheets table and i tried to full outer join users table with overtime table.  Overtime and timesheets tables have foreign keys for the primary key of the users table

Comment: Please share your tables, or we can go with `inner join` get specifics record based to the relation tables for more details please check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: whats your email or whats app then i can share my table in picture format, its hard here

Comment: `jishans24@gmail.com` or `+918401412347` in INDIA